# An object reference is required for the non-static field or method or property

Tags: c#

I am trying `Action<T,T>` delegate and got the following error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property

The event declaration looks as follows:

```
public event Action<string, string> FileStateProcess;
```

And the usage should looks like this:

```
if (FileStateProcess != null)
{
    FileStateProcess(file.FullName, temppath);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In what method is that code where you access `FileStateProcess`?

Comment: It seems that you are calling a non static event from a static method

Comment: Probably you are calling a non-static property from a static method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your declaration we can see that the `FileStateProcess` action is non-static, so I assume the method from which you are calling it is a static method. In which case, remove the `static` keyword from the method and you should be good.

Alternatively, you can make `FileStateProcess` static, but this will mean that its value will be held in the actual type, rather than in an object instance.

```
public static event Action<string, string> FileStateProcess;
```

For more info, see:

[Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide).](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)